# bash - parsing file and getting variables

Tags: bash, variables, awk, cut, netapp

I've searched and searched on here for an answer, and I think the combination of being a noob at bash, 
not knowing the right way to do this, and not searching for the right keywords has meant I can't quite get over the last hurdle.

I am looking to write a script doing some checks on our Netapp System. And I have some difficulties to fulfill the 2 first variables (VAR1 & VAR2)... I tried with cut and awk command but all my tries were unsuccessfully.

I have a text file (LUNS) and it looks like :

```
     #SAN1; SAN2
    abc1:abc1N
    abc2:abc2N 
    a3:a3N 
    abcde4:abcde4N
```

all the lines are text and numeric stuff.

for each line of the tom file, I would like to do:

- get the value of the 1st column in VAR1
- get the value of the 2nd column un VAR2
- run and get a new value VAR3 for a command with VAR1 (it will be the size of the LUN so it will be a  numeric value)
- run and get a new value VAR4 for a command with VAR2 (same as bellow)
- compare the numeric values of VAR3 & VAR4

What I did :

```
    cat tom |grep -v "#" |while read ligne ; do 
    VAR1=awk -F ";" '{print $1}'
    VAR2=awk -F ";" '{print $1}'
    specific command to get the numeric VAR3 & VAR4 values.
    #and run the comparaison  like : 
    if [ "$VAR3" -ne "$VAR4" ] 
    then
    echo "PROBLEM"
            if [ "$VAR4" -lt "$VAR3" ] ; then echo $VAR4; rm $VAR4; else echo "call support"; fi
    else 
    echo "Everything is OK"
    fi
```

my awk is not working. 
i am open to any modification in the config file, or in my way to get the VAR1 & VAR2 variables

Can I have your input on, please?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

command subtitution `$(some command)`
eg `a=$(ls)`

OR

quoting mechanism

so for `awk` to work use either

```
VAR1=$(awk -F ";" '{print $1}')
VAR2=$(awk -F ";" '{print $1}')
```

or

```
VAR1=`awk -F ";" '{print $1}'`
VAR2=`awk -F ";" '{print $1}'`
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you need to do

```
VAR1=$(echo $ligne|awk -F ";" '{print $1}')
VAR2=$(echo $ligne|awk -F ";" '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use awk

Could rewrite the loop like

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line;do
    [[ "$line" =~ ^#.*$ ]] && continue
    VAR1=${line%:*}
    VAR2=${line#*:}
    echo $VAR1
    echo $VAR2
done < test
```